# Uploading the image on facebook wall

Tags: facebook, photos

I have integrated facebook sdk. I could able to upload the image only three times. Even though I am getting the success message after upload I could not see the image on face book wall.But for first three attempts I could see the images on facebook wall.
Could I know what could be the reason? 
Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Pavan